# Apply array formula to sumifs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have Google sheet with sum-ifs functions, but I need to make it apply to the whole columns instead of just one cell and to apply automatically to new rows when there added

I know that arrays don't work with `sumifs` after doing research but I can't seem to figure out to apply an array function to this.

[image: screen grab of sheet]

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(K:K,C:C,C2,L:L,false))
```

so I tried instead to make it a =sum(if(and function instead with an array, but couldn't get that to work either. not sure how to get it to apply to the same affect as the above formula

I need to apply the following sum-ifs all the conditions are met to each cell in the selected column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically like this:

```
=QUERY({C2:C, K2:L}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col3 = FALSE 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want to pair it with list of names then use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, QUERY({C2:C, K2:L}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col3 = FALSE 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]